# how to include an html file to a single application, for example if you click add button it should display the content about add button?

Tags: html

I have a form which search for the *country code*, *name*, and a *valid date*. It has got two buttons named search and cancel. At the bottom of a form it also has four buttons named *terminate*, *add*, *edit*, and *delete*. When you click add button it should display another that has the following, but I just do not have an idea on how am I gonna make this work.

Here is the html file for both forms:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <thead>
        <hr>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            IETA-Admin-Exchange Rate
            </div>
        </thead>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>ZAR</td>
        <td>1.02</td>
        <td>13/10/15</td>
        <td>12/11/15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>LUX</td>
        <td>1.02</td>
        <td>13/10/15</td>
        <td>12/11/15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>JPY</td>
        <td>1.02</td>
        <td>13/10/15</td>
        <td>12/11/15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EEK</td>
        <td>1.02</td>
        <td>13/10/15</td>
        <td>12/11/15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CAD</td>
        <td>1.02</td>
        <td>13/10/15</td>
        <td>12/11/15</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <hr>
    <p>Search___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</p>
        <form class="form-vertical">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="code" class="col-md-8 control-label">Code:</label>
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="code">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-8 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model= "name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date" class="col-md-12 control-label">Valid On:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron text-right">
            <button ng-click="search()" class="btn btn-active btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</button>
            <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-active btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- Add html file-->

        <!-- end of Add html-->
<div class="jumbotron text-right">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button ng-click="terminateToday()" class="btn btn-active btn-sm">Terminate Today</button>
        <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-active btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</button>
        <button ng-click="edit()" class="btn btn-active btn-sm">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</button>
        <button ng-click="delete()" class="btn btn-active btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
        <!-- end of Add html-->
```

Please help!